# delayed job starts but does not process any jobs in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a rails app using delayed job, it works fine in development.
However, when I pushed to production it doesn't do anything.
Delayed job starts up fine using either one of these commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

However, once the process has started it just sits there and does not process any of the jobs in the delayed_backend_mongoid table.
I checked the delayed_job.log and it shows that the process starts up fine but does not throw any errors.
And for the heck of it I checked the production.log and there are no errors there as well.

Also if I run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:clear
```

It will delete the jobs that are in the que, so I don't think it has an issue communicating with mongodb.

I'm using

Rails 3.1.1
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally got it to work, it wasn't related to delayed job at all.  It had to do with the ruby gem Anemone.  Anemone could not get proper authorization to the mongodb.  Fixed, thanks anyways.